# storing ajax result into PHP session

Tags: php

I see examples how to fetch data from php to ajax (and display it via javascript.) As in log-in example, we can check whether there is a valid email and password entered, we can simply display "You are now logged in." Till here I understand and work out. But, now as the user logs in, I need to set the php session. 
The login form sends data to the ajax.php, which simply returns a success message. In other case, if I just use php to check valid login details, I can set php session as soon as the script finds match data.

I know I can send ajax data through URL to second php page, where it can access through $_GET. But I want to get that data into SESSION rather than sending through URL.

How I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['somevar'] = $_GET['somevar'];
```

is basically what you want. If you're sending over JSON data, then

```
session_start();
$json = json_decode($_POST['jsonvar']);
$_SESSION['somevar'] = $json['somevar'];
```

$_SESSION is an array like any other in PHP - assign to it, read from it, delete, push, pop, etc... It's only special because it's a) a superglobal b) automatically persisted for you if you use `session_start()`

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax request with form details

```
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"file.php",
        data:"your data string to pass",
        complete:function(data){
     response of ajax
          
        }
    });
```

your php file with some code

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['varable'] = $info_to_add;
 $_SESSION['varable2'] = $info_to_addother;
?>
```